# Numpy common slicing for different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-slicing

I have a function performs an operation on 2D arrays. I would like to expand its functionality to be able to work with 3D arrays, for which I would like to know if there is a way to access the vectors of each 2D array regardless of whether the input is a 3D array or a 2D array.

For example, if I have the following 2D matrix:

```
>>>arr2d=array([[0, 0],
                [1, 1]])
```

I can access the last vector using:

```
>>>arr2d[-1]
array([1, 1])
```

And if I have a 3D array like this:

```
>>>arr3d=array([[[ 0,  0],
                 [ 1,  1]],

                [[ 3,  0],
                 [ 2,  7]],

                [[ 9,  5],
                 [ 8,  6]],

                [[20,  4],
                 [ 6,  5]]])
```

I can access the last vector of each 2D submatrix using:

```
>>>arr3d[:,-1]
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 7],
       [8, 6],
       [6, 5]])
```

I would like to know if there is a common slice that I can use on both arrays to get the above results, i.e. something like the following, with `some_slice` being the same in each case:

```
>>>arr2d[some_slice]
array([1, 1])

>>>arr3d[some_slice]
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 7],
       [8, 6],
       [6, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Ellipsis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#dimensional-indexing-tools) as below:

```
print(arr2d[..., -1, :])
print(arr3d[..., -1, :])
```

**Output**

```
[1 1]
[[1 1]
 [2 7]
 [8 6]
 [6 5]]
```

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Ellipsis expands to the number of : objects needed for the selection
> tuple to index all dimensions. In most cases, this means that the
> length of the expanded selection tuple is x.ndim. **There may only be a
> single ellipsis present**

But if you want to create a function that works both for 2d and 3d arrays I suggest that you convert the 2d array two a 3d array by adding a new axis. Find a toy example below:

```
def foo_index(arr):
    if len(arr.shape) == 2:
        arr = arr[np.newaxis, :]
    return arr[:, -1]


print(foo_index(arr2d))  # two-dimensional shape
print(foo_index(arr3d))  # two-dimensional shape
```

Note that the output now have the same shape (2d), therefore code depending on the result can work regardless of a 2d or 3d input array. Note that this will not happen by using the same slice for both arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much!
The truth is that I had tried to use the `Ellipsis`, however it is a tool that I do not quite understand. Specifically, I had used `[...,-1]` instead of `[...,-1,:]`, I don't understand why the ending `:`, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `...` slice in this way:

```
arr2d[...,-1,:]
arr3d[...,-1,:]
```

in both cases you are slicing the last-but-one axis.
In general you can set `custom_slice = (Ellipsis, -1, slice(None))` and apply it to bot arrays:

```
arr2d[custom_slice]
arr3d[custom_slice]
```